# Who am I? - "Stepped On"

Tags: riddle

Here's my first attempt at a riddle, hopefully it's not too obvious. Answers should include explanations for each line.

> I'm always stepped on by others, but I don't care. 
>   I am strong as wood and cold as stone. 
>   I can never win a race; the closest I come is a tie. 
>   I'm often mistaken for a story.

Who am I?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Also inspired by CodeNewbie's answer. Are you

> a FLOOR?

*I'm always stepped on by others, but I don't care.*

> This line is obvious.

*I am strong as wood and cold as stone.*

> Floors can be made out of wood or stone.

*I can never win a race; the closest I come is a tie.*

> In mathematics, the floor function $\lfloor x \rfloor$ can never exceed $x$; the best it can do is to equal $x$ if $x$ is an integer.

*I'm often mistaken for a story.*

> A building's storeys can also be called its floors.

Comment: Ding ding ding!

Comment: OP has not heard of under-floor heating?

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> a step on a staircase?

I'm always stepped on by others, but I don't care.

> You step on the steps to go up or down.

I am strong as wood and cold as stone.

> A staircase can be made of wood or stone.

I can never win a race; the closest I come is a tie.

> Stuck with this one...

I'm often mistaken for a story.

> Steps can take you to another 'storey' of the building

Comment: That's pretty close, but not exactly the answer I was going for. The right answer has many of the same answers but also explains the clue that your answer doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by CodeNewbie's answer

I am

> an escalator

I'm always stepped on by others, but I don't care.

> people are stepping on me, but I don't care since it's my purpose

I am strong as wood and cold as stone.

> I am made of steel thus making me strong and cold

I can never win a race; the closest I come is a tie.

> I can never be ahead of people since I am always looping. I can be tie when people end their journey on me

I'm often mistaken for a story.

> Escalator can take you to another 'storey' of the building

Comment: Good guess, but that's not it either.